# How to send a document through a Telegram bot to user without a command?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to send a document through a bot to a user without the user having to enter a command. I'm using the `pyTelegramAPI` library.

I want the bot to send a document to a user on a certain day and time automatically, without the user having to type any command.  I will use the Windows task scheduler.

Comment: Wouldn't [this line from the wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#post-a-file-from-disk) work? I assume you can send the document when you start the bot. Otherwise you must provide some kind of condition such as receiving a user message, or doing some checks in the background. Maybe you can specify what exactly you need?

Comment: I want the bot to send a document to a user on a certain day and time automatically, without the user having to type any command. I will use the Windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at https://medium.com/@ManHay_Hong/how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-and-send-messages-with-python-4cf314d9fa3e

1. On Telegram, search your bot (by the username you just created), press the `Start` button or send a `/start` message.
2. Open a new tab with your browser, enter `https://api.telegram.org/bot<yourtoken>/getUpdates` , replace `<yourtoken>` with your API token, press enter and you should see something like this:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":77xxxxxxx,
"message":{"message_id":550,"from":{"id":34xxxxxxx,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Man Hay","last_name":"Hong","username":"manhay212","language_code":"en-HK"}
```

Look for `id`, for instance, `34xxxxxxx` above is the chat id. Look for yours and put it as your bot_chatID in the code.